# Interacting with a Remote MySQL Database in an Android Application

Tags: java, php, android, mysql, xampp

i am current working on a client server communication in android. 
The tutorial that i am working on can be found on : http://www.mybringback.com/tutorial-series/12924/android-tutorial-using-remote-databases-php-and-mysql-part-1/

For convenience sake, i will only be posting main **activity page (java and xml)** and **register page(java and xml)** because the problem is the same for other class.

When i build and run the project on eclipse, pressing login OR register button in registerlayout.xml, the whole application will crash. What is causing this error? Please help!!!

***Error code can be found below***

**MainActivity.java**

```
package com.example.mysqltest;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import org.apache.http.NameValuePair;
import org.apache.http.message.BasicNameValuePair;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.ProgressDialog;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.SharedPreferences;
import android.content.SharedPreferences.Editor;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.preference.PreferenceManager;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.Toast;
public class MainActivity extends Activity
implements OnClickListener{

private EditText user, pass;
private Button mSubmit, mRegister;

// Progress Dialog
private ProgressDialog pDialog;

// JSON parser class
JSONParser jsonParser = new JSONParser();

//php login script location:

//localhost :
//testing on your device
//put your local ip instead,  on windows, run CMD > ipconfig
//or in mac's terminal type ifconfig and look for the ip under en0 or en1
// private static final String LOGIN_URL = "http://xxx.xxx.x.x:1234/webservice  /login.php";

//testing on Emulator:
private static final String LOGIN_URL = "http://172.18.205.34/webservice/login.php";

//testing from a real server:
//private static final String LOGIN_URL = "http://www.yourdomain.com/webservice/login.php";

//JSON element ids from repsonse of php script:
private static final String TAG_SUCCESS = "success";
private static final String TAG_MESSAGE = "message";

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    //setup input fields
    user = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.getUsername);
    pass = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.getPassword);

    //setup buttons
    mSubmit = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btnLogin);
    mRegister = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btnRegister);

    //register listeners
    mSubmit.setOnClickListener(this);
    mRegister.setOnClickListener(this);

}

@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    switch (v.getId()) {
    case R.id.btnLogin:
            new AttemptLogin().execute();
        break;
    case R.id.btnRegister:
            Intent i = new Intent(this, Register.class);
            startActivity(i);
        break;

    default:
        break;
    }
}

class AttemptLogin extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {

     /**
     * Before starting background thread Show Progress Dialog
     * */
    boolean failure = false;

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();
        pDialog = new ProgressDialog(MainActivity.this);
        pDialog.setMessage("Attempting login...");
        pDialog.setIndeterminate(false);
        pDialog.setCancelable(true);
        pDialog.show();
    }

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
         // Check for success tag
        int success;
        String username = user.getText().toString();
        String password = pass.getText().toString();
        try {
            // Building Parameters
            List<NameValuePair> params = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
            params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("username", username));
            params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("password", password));

            Log.d("request!", "starting");
            // getting product details by making HTTP request
            JSONObject json = jsonParser.makeHttpRequest(
                   LOGIN_URL, "POST", params);

            // check your log for json response
            Log.d("Login attempt", json.toString());

            // json success tag
            success = json.getInt(TAG_SUCCESS);
            if (success == 1) {
                Log.d("Login Successful!", json.toString());
                // save user data
                SharedPreferences sp = PreferenceManager
                        .getDefaultSharedPreferences(MainActivity.this);
                Editor edit = sp.edit();
                edit.putString("username", username);
                edit.commit();

                Intent i = new Intent(MainActivity.this, ReadComments.class);
                finish();
                startActivity(i);
                return json.getString(TAG_MESSAGE);
            } else {
                Log.d("Login Failure!", json.getString(TAG_MESSAGE));
                return json.getString(TAG_MESSAGE);
            }
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return null;

    }
    /**
     * After completing background task Dismiss the progress dialog
     * **/
    protected void onPostExecute(String file_url) {
        // dismiss the dialog once product deleted
        pDialog.dismiss();
        if (file_url != null){
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, file_url, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }

    }

}

}
```

**activity_main.xml**

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
tools:context=".MainActivity" >

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/getPassword"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/getUsername"
    android:layout_below="@+id/getUsername"
    android:layout_marginTop="35dp"
    android:ems="10"
    android:inputType="textMultiLine" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/btnLogin"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignRight="@+id/textView1"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:text="Login" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/btnRegister"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/btnLogin"
    android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/btnLogin"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:text="Register" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="17dp"
    android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/btnRegister"
    android:text="Username:" />

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/getUsername"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/textView1"
    android:layout_below="@+id/textView1"
    android:ems="10"
    android:inputType="textMultiLine" >

    <requestFocus />
</EditText>

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView2"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/getPassword"
    android:layout_below="@+id/getUsername"
    android:layout_marginTop="17dp"
    android:text="Password:" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

**registerlayout.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical" >

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Username" />

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/getUsername1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:ems="10"
    android:inputType="textMultiLine" >

    <requestFocus />
</EditText>

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView2"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Password" />

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/getPassword1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:ems="10"
    android:inputType="textMultiLine" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/btnRegister1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Register" />

</LinearLayout>
```

**Register.java**

```
package com.example.mysqltest;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import org.apache.http.NameValuePair;
import org.apache.http.message.BasicNameValuePair;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.ProgressDialog;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class Register extends Activity implements OnClickListener{

private EditText user, pass;
private Button  mRegister;

 // Progress Dialog
private ProgressDialog pDialog;

// JSON parser class
JSONParser jsonParser = new JSONParser();

//php login script

//localhost :
//testing on your device
//put your local ip instead,  on windows, run CMD > ipconfig
//or in mac's terminal type ifconfig and look for the ip under en0 or en1
// private static final String LOGIN_URL = "http://xxx.xxx.x.x:1234/webservice   /register.php";

//testing on Emulator:
private static final String LOGIN_URL = "http://192.168.1.38/webservice/register.php";

//testing from a real server:
//private static final String LOGIN_URL = "http://www.yourdomain.com/webservice/register.php";

//ids
private static final String TAG_SUCCESS = "success";
private static final String TAG_MESSAGE = "message";

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.registerlayout);

    user = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.getUsername1);
    pass = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.getPassword1);

    mRegister = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btnRegister1);
    mRegister.setOnClickListener(this);

}

@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            new CreateUser().execute();

}

class CreateUser extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {

     /**
     * Before starting background thread Show Progress Dialog
     * */
    boolean failure = false;

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();
        pDialog = new ProgressDialog(Register.this);
        pDialog.setMessage("Creating User...");
        pDialog.setIndeterminate(false);
        pDialog.setCancelable(true);
        pDialog.show();
    }

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
         // Check for success tag
        int success;
        String username = user.getText().toString();
        String password = pass.getText().toString();
        try {
            // Building Parameters
            List<NameValuePair> params = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
            params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("username", username));
            params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("password", password));

            Log.d("request!", "starting");

            //Posting user data to script
            JSONObject json = jsonParser.makeHttpRequest(
                   LOGIN_URL, "POST", params);

            // full json response
            Log.d("Login attempt", json.toString());

            // json success element
            success = json.getInt(TAG_SUCCESS);
            if (success == 1) {
                Log.d("User Created!", json.toString());
                finish();
                return json.getString(TAG_MESSAGE);
            }else{
                Log.d("Login Failure!", json.getString(TAG_MESSAGE));
                return json.getString(TAG_MESSAGE);

            }
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return null;

    }
    /**
     * After completing background task Dismiss the progress dialog
     * **/
    protected void onPostExecute(String file_url) {
        // dismiss the dialog once product deleted
        pDialog.dismiss();
        if (file_url != null){
            Toast.makeText(Register.this, file_url, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }

    }

}

}
```

**config.inc.php**

```
<?php 

// These variables define the connection information for your MySQL database 
$username = "emily"; 
$password = "testing"; 
$host = "localhost"; 
$dbname = "webservice"; 


$options = array(PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_INIT_COMMAND => 'SET NAMES utf8'); 


try 
{ 

    $db = new PDO("mysql:host={$host};dbname={$dbname};charset=utf8", $username, $password, $options); 
} 
catch(PDOException $ex) 
{ 

    die("Failed to connect to the database: " . $ex->getMessage()); 
} 


$db->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION); 



$db->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_DEFAULT_FETCH_MODE, PDO::FETCH_ASSOC); 



if(function_exists('get_magic_quotes_gpc') && get_magic_quotes_gpc()) 
{ 
    function undo_magic_quotes_gpc(&$array) 
    { 
        foreach($array as &$value) 
        { 
            if(is_array($value)) 
            { 
                undo_magic_quotes_gpc($value); 
            } 
            else 
            { 
                $value = stripslashes($value); 
            } 
        } 
    } 

    undo_magic_quotes_gpc($_POST); 
    undo_magic_quotes_gpc($_GET); 
    undo_magic_quotes_gpc($_COOKIE); 
} 


header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8'); 


session_start(); 



?>
```

**login.php**

```
<?php

//load and connect to MySQL database stuff
require("config.inc.php");

if (!empty($_POST)) {
//gets user's info based off of a username.
$query = " 
        SELECT 
            id, 
            username, 
            password
        FROM users 
        WHERE 
            username = :username 
    ";

$query_params = array(
    ':username' => $_POST['username']
);

try {
    $stmt   = $db->prepare($query);
    $result = $stmt->execute($query_params);
}
catch (PDOException $ex) {
    // For testing, you could use a die and message. 
    //die("Failed to run query: " . $ex->getMessage());

    //or just use this use this one to product JSON data:
    $response["success"] = 0;
    $response["message"] = "Database Error1. Please Try Again!";
    die(json_encode($response));

}

//This will be the variable to determine whether or not the user's information is correct.
//we initialize it as false.
$validated_info = false;

//fetching all the rows from the query
$row = $stmt->fetch();
if ($row) {
    //if we encrypted the password, we would unencrypt it here, but in our case we just
    //compare the two passwords
    if ($_POST['password'] === $row['password']) {
        $login_ok = true;
    }
}

// If the user logged in successfully, then we send them to the private members-only page 
// Otherwise, we display a login failed message and show the login form again 
if ($login_ok) {
    $response["success"] = 1;
    $response["message"] = "Login successful!";
    die(json_encode($response));
} else {
    $response["success"] = 0;
    $response["message"] = "Invalid Credentials!";
    die(json_encode($response));
}
} else {
?>
    <h1>Login</h1> 
      <form action="login.php" method="post"> 
        Username:<br /> 
        <input type="text" name="username" placeholder="username" /> 
        <br /><br /> 
        Password:<br /> 
        <input type="password" name="password" placeholder="password" value="" /> 
        <br /><br /> 
        <input type="submit" value="Login" /> 
    </form> 
    <a href="register.php">Register</a>
<?php
}

?>
```

**register.php**

```
<?php


require("config.inc.php");

//if posted data is not empty
if (!empty($_POST)) {
//If the username or password is empty when the user submits
//the form, the page will die.
//Using die isn't a very good practice, you may want to look into
//displaying an error message within the form instead.  
//We could also do front-end form validation from within our Android App,
//but it is good to have a have the back-end code do a double check.
if (empty($_POST['username']) || empty($_POST['password'])) {


    // Create some data that will be the JSON response 
    $response["success"] = 0;
    $response["message"] = "Please Enter Both a Username and Password.";

    //die will kill the page and not execute any code below, it will also
    //display the parameter... in this case the JSON data our Android
    //app will parse
    die(json_encode($response));
}

//if the page hasn't died, we will check with our database to see if there is
//already a user with the username specificed in the form.  ":user" is just
//a blank variable that we will change before we execute the query.  We
//do it this way to increase security, and defend against sql injections
$query        = " SELECT 1 FROM users WHERE username = :user";
//now lets update what :user should be
$query_params = array(
    ':user' => $_POST['username']
);

//Now let's make run the query:
try {
    // These two statements run the query against your database table. 
    $stmt   = $db->prepare($query);
    $result = $stmt->execute($query_params);
}
catch (PDOException $ex) {
    // For testing, you could use a die and message. 
    //die("Failed to run query: " . $ex->getMessage());

    //or just use this use this one to product JSON data:
    $response["success"] = 0;
    $response["message"] = "Database Error1. Please Try Again!";
    die(json_encode($response));
}

//fetch is an array of returned data.  If any data is returned,
//we know that the username is already in use, so we murder our
//page
$row = $stmt->fetch();
if ($row) {
    // For testing, you could use a die and message. 
    //die("This username is already in use");

    //You could comment out the above die and use this one:
    $response["success"] = 0;
    $response["message"] = "I'm sorry, this username is already in use";
    die(json_encode($response));
}

//If we have made it here without dying, then we are in the clear to 
//create a new user.  Let's setup our new query to create a user.  
//Again, to protect against sql injects, user tokens such as :user and :pass
$query = "INSERT INTO users ( username, password ) VALUES ( :user, :pass ) ";

//Again, we need to update our tokens with the actual data:
$query_params = array(
    ':user' => $_POST['username'],
    ':pass' => $_POST['password']
);

//time to run our query, and create the user
try {
    $stmt   = $db->prepare($query);
    $result = $stmt->execute($query_params);
}
catch (PDOException $ex) {
    // For testing, you could use a die and message. 
    //die("Failed to run query: " . $ex->getMessage());

    //or just use this use this one:
    $response["success"] = 0;
    $response["message"] = "Database Error2. Please Try Again!";
    die(json_encode($response));
}

//If we have made it this far without dying, we have successfully added
//a new user to our database.  We could do a few things here, such as 
//redirect to the login page.  Instead we are going to echo out some
//json data that will be read by the Android application, which will login
//the user (or redirect to a different activity, I'm not sure yet..)
$response["success"] = 1;
$response["message"] = "Username Successfully Added!";
echo json_encode($response);

//for a php webservice you could do a simple redirect and die.
//header("Location: login.php"); 
//die("Redirecting to login.php");


} else {
?>
<h1>Register</h1> 
<form action="register.php" method="post"> 
    Username:<br /> 
    <input type="text" name="username" value="" /> 
    <br /><br /> 
    Password:<br /> 
    <input type="password" name="password" value="" /> 
    <br /><br /> 
    <input type="submit" value="Register New User" /> 
</form>
<?php
}

?>
```

**error logcat**

```
10-28 08:52:43.894: D/dalvikvm(833): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 71K, 8% free 2660K/2880K,   paused 41ms, total 53ms
10-28 08:52:44.004: D/request!(833): starting
10-28 08:52:46.224: I/Choreographer(833): Skipped 30 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
10-28 08:52:46.524: D/dalvikvm(833): GC_CONCURRENT freed 57K, 7% free 3009K/3212K, paused 84ms+37ms, total 297ms
10-28 08:52:47.064: E/JSON Parser(833): Error parsing data org.json.JSONException: Value <!DOCTYPE of type java.lang.String cannot be converted to JSONObject
10-28 08:52:47.064: W/dalvikvm(833): threadid=15: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x40a71930)
10-28 08:52:47.144: E/AndroidRuntime(833): FATAL EXCEPTION: AsyncTask #5
10-28 08:52:47.144: E/AndroidRuntime(833): java.lang.RuntimeException: An error occured while executing doInBackground()
10-28 08:52:47.144: E/AndroidRuntime(833):  at android.os.AsyncTask$3.done(AsyncTask.java:299)
10-28 08:52:47.144: E/AndroidRuntime(833):  at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.finishCompletion(FutureTask.java:352)
10-28 08:52:47.144: E/AndroidRuntime(833):  at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.setException(FutureTask.java:219)
10-28 08:52:47.144: E/AndroidRuntime(833):  at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:239)
10-28 08:52:47.144: E/AndroidRuntime(833):  at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:230)
10-28 08:52:47.144: E/AndroidRuntime(833):  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1080)
10-28 08:52:47.144: E/AndroidRuntime(833):  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:573)
10-28 08:52:47.144: E/AndroidRuntime(833):  at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:856)
10-28 08:52:47.144: E/AndroidRuntime(833): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
10-28 08:52:47.144: E/AndroidRuntime(833):  at com.example.mysqltest.MainActivity$AttemptLogin.doInBackground(MainActivity.java:128)
10-28 08:52:47.144: E/AndroidRuntime(833):  at com.example.mysqltest.MainActivity$AttemptLogin.doInBackground(MainActivity.java:1)
10-28 08:52:47.144: E/AndroidRuntime(833):  at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:287)
10-28 08:52:47.144: E/AndroidRuntime(833):  at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:234)
10-28 08:52:47.144: E/AndroidRuntime(833):  ... 4 more
10-28 08:52:47.864: I/Choreographer(833): Skipped 87 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
10-28 08:52:50.844: E/WindowManager(833): Activity com.example.mysqltest.MainActivity has leaked window com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView{40d24b58 V.E.....    R.....ID 0,0-563,96} that was originally added here
10-28 08:52:50.844: E/WindowManager(833): android.view.WindowLeaked: Activity com.example.mysqltest.MainActivity has leaked window com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView{40d24b58 V.E..... R.....ID 0,0-563,96} that was originally added here
10-28 08:52:50.844: E/WindowManager(833):   at android.view.ViewRootImpl.<init>(ViewRootImpl.java:354)
10-28 08:52:50.844: E/WindowManager(833):   at android.view.WindowManagerGlobal.addView(WindowManagerGlobal.java:216)
10-28 08:52:50.844: E/WindowManager(833):   at android.view.WindowManagerImpl.addView(WindowManagerImpl.java:69)
10-28 08:52:50.844: E/WindowManager(833):   at android.app.Dialog.show(Dialog.java:281)
10-28 08:52:50.844: E/WindowManager(833):   at com.example.mysqltest.MainActivity$AttemptLogin.onPreExecute(MainActivity.java:106)
10-28 08:52:50.844: E/WindowManager(833):   at android.os.AsyncTask.executeOnExecutor(AsyncTask.java:586)
10-28 08:52:50.844: E/WindowManager(833):   at android.os.AsyncTask.execute(AsyncTask.java:534)
10-28 08:52:50.844: E/WindowManager(833):   at com.example.mysqltest.MainActivity.onClick(MainActivity.java:80)
10-28 08:52:50.844: E/WindowManager(833):   at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4204)
10-28 08:52:50.844: E/WindowManager(833):   at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:17355)
10-28 08:52:50.844: E/WindowManager(833):   at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:725)
10-28 08:52:50.844: E/WindowManager(833):   at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
10-28 08:52:50.844: E/WindowManager(833):   at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
10-28 08:52:50.844: E/WindowManager(833):   at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5041)
10-28 08:52:50.844: E/WindowManager(833):   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
10-28 08:52:50.844: E/WindowManager(833):   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
10-28 08:52:50.844: E/WindowManager(833):   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:793)
10-28 08:52:50.844: E/WindowManager(833):   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:560)
10-28 08:52:50.844: E/WindowManager(833):   at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
10-28 08:52:50.844: I/Choreographer(833): Skipped 73 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
```

Comment: debug 101 : what's at line `com.example.mysqltest.MainActivity$AttemptLogin.doInBackground(MainActivity.java:128)` ?

Answer (score 0):

you are Asyntask getting the url argument but you didn't send the url inside the execute method
  `new AttemptLogin().execute(LOGIN_URL);`

```
@Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        switch (v.getId()) {
        case R.id.btnLogin:
        ->        new AttemptLogin().execute(LOGIN_URL);

            break;
        case R.id.btnRegister:
                Intent i = new Intent(this, Register.class);
                startActivity(i);
            break;

        default:
            break;
        }
    }
```

Comment: I've done it your way but the application still crash when i press either button :'( PLEASE HELP ME!!

Comment: @Nambi : which would be irrelevant since the SO never refers to `args` in the doInBackground method.

Answer (score 0):

I had a different error when I had this problem which said '`The value <br...`' Can't remember the rest, however the problem that I found was within the PHP. In your Login.PHP file, you can see '`$validated_info = false;`', however, you are actually using '`$login_ok`' as your boolean variable. Wherever you see '`$login_ok`', change that to '`$validated_info`'. Or change '`$validated_info`' to '`$login_ok`'. This fixed mine for the moment, however I get your error when the details entered aren't in the database.